# How to insert element to a specific index in 3d numpy array without using python loops?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a 3-dimensional NumPy array of shape (480, 640, 30), where each 2d array's shape is (480,640), and every element on this 2d array is part of what effectively is a FIFO buffer along the depth dimension (so in effect 480x640 buffers each of size 30 exist). With each new 2d frame that is received, each buffer is updated depending on a boolean mask 2d array (if the corresponding index in mask array is False, then update the corresponding buffer with the value from this new frame, if True, then don't). I'm using another 2d array to keep track of where to add a new element from a new frame to each of the buffers, if an element is added to a buffer the counter for that specific index is incremented (buffer's median is taken when used, so the order of elements does not matter)
I have been able to implement this in O(n^2) time using loops this way:

```
buffer = np.full((30,480,640), -1, dtype=int) #initialized with -1, values added range from 0 -> 255
bool_mask = np.random.choice([True, False], size=(480,640), replace=True, p=None) 
#here I am using the same mask for every loop but in reality mask would change with each input frame
counter = np.zeros((480,640), dtype=np.uint8) 
rand_frame = np.random.randint(1, 5, size=(480,640), dtype=int) #just a random array to replicate the new frame that is received

for m in range(100): #in the final implementation, frames are received continuously and buffer is updated, I've used this loop to replicate that process
    for i in range(buffer.shape[1]):
        for k in range(buffer.shape[2]):
            if not bool_mask[i][k]:
                buffer[counter[i][k]%30][i][k] = rand_frame[i][k] #modulus used to replicate a FIFO buffer insertion
                counter[i][k] += 1
```

This logic works as intended, but it is very slow at 850 ms. I need it to run at 1 ms, so loops won't do. I've tried using np.where, but the updation for each element may or may not occur, resulting in the depth index in the counter being different for each index on the 2d array, so np.where won't do, plus if I use it there has to be an addition of element either way, whereas in my case updation of fifo buffer is conditional. I've been searching for alternatives that do selective updation for corresponding indices but have had no luck.
I'd really appreciate help on this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [Boolean indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing):

```py
import numpy as np

# use smaller dimensions so problem runs in reasonable time
w = 50
h = 70
d = 7

bool_mask = np.random.choice([True, False], size=(h,w), replace=True, p=None) 
rand_frame = np.random.randint(1, 5, size=(h,w), dtype=int)

# for-loop solution
def ex1():
    counter = np.zeros((h,w), dtype=np.uint8) 
    buffer1 = np.full((d,h,w), -1, dtype=int)
    for m in range(d):
        for i in range(buffer1.shape[1]):
            for k in range(buffer1.shape[2]):
                if not bool_mask[i][k]:
                    buffer1[counter[i][k]%d][i][k] = rand_frame[i][k] #modulus used to replicate a FIFO buffer insertion
                    counter[i][k] += 1
    return buffer1, counter


# boolean indexing solution
def ex2():
    counter = np.zeros((h,w), dtype=np.uint8) 
    buffer2 = np.full((d,h,w), -1, dtype=int) #initialized with -1, values added range from 0 -> 255
    for m in range(d):
        buffer2[m%d][~bool_mask] = rand_frame[~bool_mask]
        counter[~bool_mask] += 1
    return buffer2, counter


b1, c1 = ex1()
b2, c2 = ex2()

# verify results are the same
print(f'{(b1 == b2).all() = }')
print(f'{(c1 == c2).all() = }')
```

On my system (Python 3.9.7, numpy 1.21.4), this gives

```
(b1 == b2).all() = True
(c1 == c2).all() = True
```

and

```py
In [57]: timeit ex1()
80.2 ms ± 159 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [58]: timeit ex2
23.8 ns ± 0.0931 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Comment: The insertion of new elements should not be across a common z-index value, which is what is happening in the boolean indexing solution. The insertion index along that axis varies depending on the counter for that corresponding index.

Comment: Fair enough - could you alter your example to reflect what you mean?  As you can see, yor solution and mine currently give the same results (I don't think it's just due to the reduced problem size, but maybe?).  FWIW, it's of course possible that there won't be a way to efficiently do what you want in numpy, in which case you could look at Numba, or Cython, to make the inner loops fast.